# Change Element value in SimpleXML by xpath search by Attribute value

Tags: php, json, xml, xpath, simplexml

Change Element from SimpleXML xpath

I want to change an Element Value by an xpath search after an certain attribute.

I have a XML File, where I want to change the value of all Elements with the Attribute "No"

```
<Value1>
        <Type No="001">ABC</Type>
</Value1>
    <Value2>
        <Type No="002">CDE</Type>
        <ID No="003">DEF</ID>
        <ShareID No="004">GFH</ShareID>
    </Value2>
    ...
    ...
```

In PHP I wrote a Script which should search for all Elements with the Attribute "No" and should alter the Value by a given Json Table. Inside the Table I have pairs with the ID and value.

As a first Prototype i just wrote an script which changes the First Element No='001' to "Test";

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents( "php://input" ); //$data is now the string '[1,2,3]';

$data = json_decode( $data ); //$data is now a php array array(1,2,3)

$test = $data->data;

// load the document

// Load XML File 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data->xmlFile);

//TODO Change each Element which is in the JSON Table

$result  = $xml->xpath("//*[@No='001']");

// TODO Change every Element by corresponding JSON Table

$result[0] = "Test";

// save the updated document
$xml->asXML($data->xmlFile);

echo "OK";

?>
```

As a result from the xpath Function I receive the following array:

```
    SimpleXMLElement
        @attributes:array(1)
            0:"ABC"
```

The way I access the result above doesn't work. How can I access the Value of the Element ("ABC") in the SimpleXMLElement in the result of the xpath request? I furthe development I want to

Comment: use DOMDocument, trust me, it's way better

Comment: Got it working with DOMDocument without ease.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (sibling to XPath), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files and especially best suited for processing many elements. In fact, you can even pass parameters like *'test'* from PHP to XSLT. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class which may require enabling the php_xsl extension in .ini file with web server restart.

Below demonstrates adjusting for one *Type* element with `@No='001'` condition with a parameter value passed from PHP. You can extend the number of parameters and templates as needed. The [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) copies entire document as is prior to your adjustments.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- Initializing Parameters -->
   <xsl:param name="php_param"/>

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Assign New Text Value by Parameter -->
    <xsl:template match="Type[@No='001']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$php_param"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
...

// LOAD XML
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load($data->xmlFile);

// LOAD XSLT 
$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// SET PARAMETER VALUE
$proc->setParameter('', 'php_param', 'test');

// TRANSFORM SOURCE
$newXML = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents($data->xmlFile, $newXML);
```